# Creating a inline span class in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create the following span class.

[image]

Actually I'm new to the UI designing and I couldn't to create this button exactly as the image.This is my code so far.

```css
.white-button {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #eaeaea;
  text-align: justify;
}

.green-button {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #eaeaea;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<span style="display: inline;">
        <span class="white-button">$ 50
        </span>
<span class="green-button">Give Now
        </span>
</span>
<font style="color:#20A1D4; text-align:left">
  <i><br>Why give $5o?</i>
</font>
```

Can anyone help me ! Thank you.

Comment: It might be easier to "debug" if you post a picture of what you're getting.  As well as what browser you're using.

Comment: Exactly, like which image?

Comment: Why are you using `span`s to create a button and a text input?

Comment: The image is in the post. Look at it again.

Comment: To create them inline

Comment: Better to use bootstrap for this

Comment: The `<font>` element doesn't even exist anymore

Comment: @VaibhavRajput no! no! no! no! no! You want to use an entire framework to style a button and a text input?

Comment: Do you *really* need to use span elements to reach your goal?

Comment: but for `span` element `display: inline-block` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using `inputs` which provides semantic meaning.

```css
.text-input {
  width:80px;
  height:29px;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:4px;
  font-size:10pt;
  color:#777;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.green-button {
  width: 88px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius:4px;
  margin-left:8px;
  background-color:#1cbc2d;
  border-style: solid;
  border: 1px solid #1cbc2d;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:10pt;
}

.why-give {
  color:#20A1D4;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size:9pt;
  margin-top:6px;
}
```

```html
<input class="text-input" type="text" value="$50"/>
<input class="green-button" type="button" value="Give Now"/>

<div class="why-give">Why give $50?</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is something you can start with:

```css
.white-button{
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color:#eaeaea;
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.green-button{
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color:#eaeaea;
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #00be1c;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.why {
  color:#20A1D4;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="white-button">$ 50 </div>
  <div class="green-button">Give Now</div>
</div>

<span class="why">Why give $5o?</span>
```

The `inline` was not what you were looking for. You need `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make the changes below:

```css
.white-button{
   width: 70px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color:#eaeaea;
   text-align: justify;
   display: flex;
   padding-left: 10px;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: left;
   border-radius: 3px;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 13px;
}
.green-button{
   border: none;
   text-align: justify;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   margin-left: 15px;
   background-color: #00be1c;
   color: #fff;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   border-radius: 3px;
   font-size: 13px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span style="display: flex;">
    <span class="white-button">$ 50
    </span>
    <span class="green-button">Give Now
    </span>
  </span>
  <font style="color:#20A1D4; text-align:left;">
    <i>Why give $5o?</i>
    </font>
```